# Python if is returning wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I have a if statement to check if two variables returns the same, which means the client exist. Right now the if statement should be true, I dont understand why it doesn't.

```
client_status= subprocess.check_output("nsostatus | grep %s | awk '{ print $1 }'" %client_name, shell=True)
print client_name
print client_status

if client_name == client_status:
        print "client already exist"
else:
        print "client doesn't exist"
```

When I run the script, this is what I get:

```
nagios-client
nagios-client
client doesn't exist
```

EDIT: Running it with repr()

```
nagios-client 
nagios-client\n
```

Comment: Could you try `print repr(...)` and `print type(...)`?

Comment: try `print repr(client_name), repr(client_status), type(client_name), type(client_status)`

Comment: It gives me: 'nagios-client'
'nagios-client\n'

Comment: It looks like `client_status` has a trailing newline, so the two are obviously not equal.

Comment: So, there was an extra blank line you left out of the output in the original post?

Comment: I suggest you change the title to "string comparison not consistent with appearance of strings when printed..."

Comment: I have been burned by this one before ... never again though :D

Comment: In this case I'd expect an extra blank line in the output, which would have made the issue more obvious; be precise when replicating outputs on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a trailing new-line or whitespace

> "\n"

or

> " "

... try...

```
if client_name.strip() == client_status.strip():
```

Comment: You can read in more detail by reading the documentation here https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html ... to summarize, the strip() will remove whatever characters you pass into strip from the beginning and end of the string. If no characters are passed, then leading and trailing whitespace is removed, so in your case since the \n is the only "leading OR trailing whitespace" and I am not passing arguments to strip(), then yes, only the \n will be removed